# A way to match Lisp characters containing a parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, parsing, match, regex-lookarounds

I am writing a Lisp parser in Python as part of a compiler project. My tokenizer works something like this:

```py
def tokenize(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        comment_free = remove_comments(file.read())
    return comment_free.replace("(", " ( ").replace(")", " ) ").split()
```

Lisp characters are a little bit different: the character `a` would be `#\a`, `(` would be `#\(`, et cetera. For characters that contain a left or right parenthesis, they are wrongly split apart by the tokenizer into two separate pieces (`#\` and `(` or `)`).

I can match the character indicator with `[^#\]` and parenthesis with `\(|\)`, but how would I create a pattern that checks if a part of the code does not start with a character indicator and follows with a left or right parenthesis? If I can make such a pattern I can replace all such instances with a parenthesis that has spaces around it. I thought that `([^#\\])(\(|\))*` would work but it does not work in all cases. Does anyone proficient with regex know how to figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how would I create a pattern that checks if a part of the code does
> not start with a character indicator and follows with a left or right
> parenthesis?

You might use a negative lookbehind to check that the indicator is not on the left, and match either `(` or `)` using a character class instead of an alternation.

```
(?<!#\\)[()]
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!#\\)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is directly to the left is not `#\`
- `[()]` Match either `(` or `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/joNiUJ/1)

---

If the indicator is either `#` or `\\` you could use 2 character classes:

```
(?<![#\\])[()]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7CEulg/1)